# Can webpack import staticly with a dynamic path

Tags: typescript, webpack, import, gatsby, dynamic-import

I have a project using TypeScript, Webpack, React and Gatsby, and I want to import a whole bunch of images of different resolutions and webp versions for performance.

I've started importing my images:

```
import Project1Screenshot640 from './images/projects/screenshots/640/project1.jpg'
import Project1Screenshot1280 from './images/projects/screenshots/1280/project1.jpg'
import Project1Screenshot1526 from './images/projects/screenshots/1526/project1.jpg'
import Project1Screenshot640Webp from './images/projects/screenshots/640/project1.webp'
import Project1Screenshot1280Webp from './images/projects/screenshots/1280/project1.webp'
import Project1Screenshot1526Webp from './images/projects/screenshots/1526/project1.webp'
// ... I've skipped the rest because it is a long list of imports.

const projects = {
  'project-1': {
    title: 'Project 1',
    screenshot: {
      640: [Project1Screenshot640, Project1Screenshot640Webp],
      1280: [Project1Screenshot1280, Project1Screenshot1280Webp],
      1526: [Project1Screenshot1526, Project1Screenshot1526Webp],
    },
  },
  // ...
}
```

But I've realised this is highly unmaintainable and it would be much better to generate these imports at compile time.

Something like the following would be better...

```
const generateProject = (id, title) => {
  import Screenshot640 from `./images/projects/screenshots/640/${id}.jpg`
  // ...
  import Screenshot640Webp from `./images/projects/screenshots/640/${id}.webp`
  // ...

  return {
    title,
    screenshot: [
      640: [Screenshot640, Screenshot640Webp],
      // ...
    ],
  }
}

const projects = {
  'project-1': generateProject('project-1', 'Project 1')
}
```

But unfortunately you cant import with a dynamic path (that I know of) without doing it asynchronously with `const Screenshot640 = await import('...')`.

---

If there anyway I can generate this list of project imports using webpack/gatsby during build which will be available in the compiled code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require` instead of `import` which will lazy load at compile time.

- **require**: lazy load at compile time.
- **import**: lazy load at runtime.

Source: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6125#issuecomment-351642743